# Changing from existing nodejs installation through apt to NVM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with existing NodeJS installed through apt. 
(currently on version `9.11.1`)
I want to uninstall this and switch to NVM without destroying other dependencies (like yarn) and preferrably my whole system. I need to do these cleanly and I don't want to risk missing a step. Can you please help me?

Comment: Yarn is a globally installed dependency/node_module, so changing to nvm will require re-installing them. Just note down all globally installed node_modules (`npm ls -g --depth 0`), then uninstall node via apt, install nvm, install the desired node version and re-install all global packages. Don't forget to update your `$Path` accordingly. Depending whether in some places absolute paths to the current yarn/npm are set, these have to be updates as well

Comment: Is there another way in Ubuntu? I'm coming from mac then I only run `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node` then `brew unlink node`. After that two steps, I installed node through NVM. Yarn is not destroyed.

Comment: Ok, I maybe need to specify my statement. It of course depends on which directory you specify to be used to store global npm dependencies. If it's the same in the brew installed node and nvm installed node than no re-installation is required. By default nvm uses a separate directory of global packages for each node version, as the global packages may require different dependencies for example. Not sure what you mean by "another way". You can maybe arrange it to re-use apt node installed global packages, but I wouldn't recommend that, as it's better to freshly install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

You can install `nvm` on top of your system `node`, without losing anything (although `node` and `npm` themselves will be shadowed by the `nvm`-managed `node`).

Separately, you can run `npm ls -g --depth=0` to get a list of your global modules, and then you can reinstall those after you've installed and activated an `nvm`-managed `node`.

If you installed yarn a different way than `npm install -g yarn`, then uninstalling your system `node`/`npm` shouldn't impact it.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help and info. I thought that `sudo apt remove` works like `purge` and it would destroy dependencies, but I tried it and it worked.